# Open EML file in Outlook using Add-In?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Using Outlook Add-In (VSTO) can I open an EML file from disk and "display" it?

I've tried this...

```
Dim filename As String = "c:\test\_test.eml"
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.OpenSharedItem(filename), Outlook.MailItem)
mail.Display()
```

But Outlook throws an exception saying path is not valid even though it is.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSharedItem does not work with EML files.
Outlook Object Model would not let you access EML files. You can either

1. Parse the EML file (or use an available component), create new item in Outlook and set all properties one at a time
2. If you were using C++ or Delphi, you could have used  [IConverterSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960231.aspx) MAPI interface to import the data
3. If using Redemption is an option, you can use something like the following (off the top of my head):

   dim Session as Redemption.RDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
     Session.MAPIOBJECT = Me.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
     dim Drafts as Redemption.RDOFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
     dim mail as Redemption.RDOMAil = Drafts.Items.Add 
     mail.Sent = true
     mail.Import "c:\temp\test,eml", 1024 'olRfc922
     mail.Save
     'now reopen in OOM 
     dim oMail as Outlook.MailItem = Me.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(mail.EntryId)
     dim forwardedMail as Outlook.MailItem = oMail.Forward
     forwardedMail.Display()