How to open eml file: "Invalid path or URL"
I have a snippet of VBA code where I want to press a button in Excel that will open an Outlook template.
I get an error

Invalid path or URL

Sub emailBugReport()
    Dim myoutapp As Object
    Dim myitem As Object
    
    Set myoutapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myitem = myoutapp.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\Users\kaiba\OneDrive\Desktop\test.eml")
    
    myitem.Display
End Sub

The filepath is correct.
I thought it had to do with the OneDrive, but when I removed it, it gave me another error saying that VBA couldn't find the file.

In the Immediate pane what does ? Dir("C:\Users\kaiba\OneDrive\Desktop\test.eml") give you?

Are you sure that this file-type '.eml' is something OpenSharedItem can handle? the Microsoft documents only talk about .vcf , .ics, .msg. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271082/11695049
